# Did you forget to run "composer require symfony/security-core"? Unknown function "is_granted" in "xxx.twig"

Tags: php, symfony

I updated a Symfony project from 4.4 to 5.4. First I was going to 5.0, add some fixes and checked the project. It worked well. Then I was going to 5.4. Now I get the message that "is_granted" is unknown in twig. Security-Bundle is installed and also loaded via bundles.php.

The security.yaml:

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    encoders:
        App\Entity\Benutzer:
            algorithm: bcrypt
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Benutzer
                property: loginname
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-gd": "^7.3",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "v1.2.6",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.5",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/console": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/doctrine-bridge": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/security-core": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/validator": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.4.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.3",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "5.4.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong or an hint how to debug this?

Thanks!

Alex

Comment: Your composer.json seems to be missing dependencies such as twig/twig and you have things like the twig-bundle in the dev section.  Maybe a result of your manual legacy updates?  Consider creating a new 5.4 project and then just compare your composer.json file with the new one.

Answer (score 2):

In symfony 5.4 you have to install "twig/extra-bundle" manually. It should resolve the issue with

```
composer require twig/extra-bundle
```

Comment: I upgraded a Symfony 5 project to 6.0.4 and ran into this issue.  Resolved by installing twig/extra-bundle.